# How to get the html object who called the onmouseover function method in JSP?

Tags: javascript, dom

I write a html file with some JSP in it.A html tag has a onmouseover listener.And when the mouseover method is called by moving mouse on the tag's innerhtml, how can I get the current html tag object? BTW,The "this" pointer is not pointing to the tag element.

```
function dosth(){  
   //TODO: get the object who calls this method.
}
....
<mytag onmouseover="dosth()">innerHTML</mytag>
```

In above example,how can i get the mytag node ? mytag is not allowed to have an id.

Comment: Thanks very much.But i want to know that who actually invokes the onmouseover method when my mouse is over the innerHTML?Is the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<mytag onmouseover="dosth(this);">innerHTML</mytag>`

The first argument sent to `dosth` will be the element that called it.

Comment: If I already have some parameter in the dosth() function, like dosth(p1,p2).So u mean p1 is the object who calls the dosth method?